# Multiple Enum Classes in one Java File

Tags: java, arrays, enums, constants

I have 3 String arrays with constants. eg:

```
 String[] digit = {"one", "two", "three"};
 String[] teen= {"ten", "twenty", "thirty"};
 String[] anchors = {"hundred", "thousand", "million"};
```

I'm thinking of transferring these to enums separately, so I will have 3 enum classes: `digit`, `teen` and `anchors` with `getValue` methods implemented. But I don't want to have them in separate files as I have only small data and same type of data. What is the best way to have all these with access methods in same meaningful java file?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

They can be three inner classes like this:

```
public class Types {
  public enum Digits {...}
  public enum Teens {...}
  ....
}
```

Then refer them `Types.Digits.ONE`, `Types.Teen.TWENTY` etc.

You can also use static imports like this:

```
import Types.Digits;
import Types.Teen;
```

..

in order to have shorter references: `Digits.ONE`, `Teen.TWENTY` etc.

Comment: The only suggestion I would make is to change the signature of the enums to `public static enum`. That way, we can use a static import on the needed enums and save a bit of typing for the user.

Comment: enums are already static - you don't have to declare them as static (like interfaces).

Comment: Right you are. I'm sure I learned that at some point. Still, unless using the fully qualified name adds readability or clarity, I would still suggest going with the static import, though that's really a point of personal preference, I suppose.