# Multiple Enum Classes in One Java File 2

Tags: java, enums

I just learned about enums and am a bit confused. I want to declare my enums all in one File I found this question and for all I can see did exactly that

[Multiple Enum Classes in one Java File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017729/multiple-enum-classes-in-one-java-file)

only that it does not work

```
public class DERstring{

public enum Fertigkeit 
{
    UEBER = "Überreden"; 
    HEIML = "Heimlichkeit"; 
    SUCHE = "Suchen";
}

public enum Terrain
{
    LEICHT = "leicht";
    MITTEL = "mittelschwer";
    UNPASS = "unpassierbar";
}
}
```

for each inner ennum class eclipse gives me the Error "insert 'EnumBody to complete ClassBodyDeclaration. What is it I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: clear/rebuild your project once.

Comment: You're defining enums in Java incorrectly, this needs to be a COMMA separated list of enumerated values and if you need an additional string value look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067352/can-set-enum-start-value-in-java

Comment: Look below at Peter's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax.
Try something like this:

```
public class DERstring{

        public enum Fertigkeit 
        {
         UEBER("Überreden"), 
         HEIML("Heimlichkeit"),
         SUCHE("Suchen");

         private String name;

         private Fertigkeit(String name){
            this.name=name;
         }

         public String getName() {
            return name;
         }

    }

.....other enums classes...
```

}